# Mutate column based on another data frame with multiple matches

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frames

df1

```
ID    PMT_DATE
100   2015/01/01
100   2015/02/01
100   2015/04/01 
200   2016/01/01
200   2016/02/01
```

and df2

```
ID    DATE         STATUS    
100   2014/12/31   A
100   2015/03/15   B
200   2015/12/31   A  
200   2016/06/01   C
```

I would create a data frame which is df1 with the STATUS column from df2. If the PMT_DATE column in df1 is greater than or equal to the DATE column in df2, the associated status in df2 should be placed in the new data frame. The resulting dataframe should look like this

```
ID    PMT_DATE     STATUS
100   2015/01/01   A
100   2015/02/01   A
100   2015/04/01   B 
200   2016/01/01   A
200   2016/02/01   A
```

Normally I would join the two tables, create a new column and perform calculations with mutate and get rid of the columns I don't need anymore, but since there are multiple matches in the ID column in df1 and df2, I can't quite implement that strategy.

EDIT: For multiple matches, I want the latest status. For instance, the last row with ID == 100 would fall under both Status == A and Status == B, but I only want status B. Also, the ID field in both dataframes represents the same thing (i.e. a join by ID is what I want).

I was thinking of something along the lines of

```
new_df <- df1 %>% rowwise() $>% do() ...
```

But I am not sure how to fill in the rest to achieve what I need.

Comment: Shouldn't the third row of `df1` have a status of A and B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using `dplyr`. The idea is to join the table first and filter out the row with `PMT_DATE >= DATE`. I think you only want the latest `STATUS` (`STATUS` associate with the latest `DATE`).

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by="ID") %>%
  filter(PMT_DATE >= DATE) %>% 
  group_by(ID, PMT_DATE) %>% 
  slice(n()) %>% # get the latest status
  select(-DATE) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#      ID   PMT_DATE STATUS
#   <int>      <chr>  <chr>
# 1   100 2015/01/01      A
# 2   100 2015/02/01      A
# 3   100 2015/04/01      B
# 4   200 2016/01/01      A
# 5   200 2016/02/01      A
```

Comment: Did OP specify that a join needed to be performed by ID? (note that I have no problem with your solution, and think it's quite good)

Comment: hmm... no actually. I probably make too many assumptions. We can ask OP to clarify.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, a join by ID is what I wanted.

Comment: @ArzaanK you should edit your question, you should also specify how multiple matches should be treated (as is the case for `ID` == 100 and `PMT_DATE` == 2015/04/01)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if *rolling joins* are available with `dplyr` yet. This is what I would do with `data.table` to get the *latest* `STATUS`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[setDT(df1), on = .(ID, DATE = PMT_DATE), roll = Inf]
```

> ```
>     ID       DATE STATUS
> 1: 100 2015-01-01      A
> 2: 100 2015-02-01      A
> 3: 100 2015-04-01      B
> 4: 200 2016-01-01      A
> 5: 200 2016-02-01      A
> ```

#### Data

```
df1 <- readr::read_table(
  "ID    PMT_DATE
100   2015/01/01
100   2015/02/01
100   2015/04/01 
200   2016/01/01
200   2016/02/01"
)
df2 <- readr::read_table(
  "ID    DATE         STATUS    
100   2014/12/31   A
100   2015/03/15   B
200   2015/12/31   A  
200   2016/06/01   C"
)
```

Comment: Or instead of making a new table... `setDT(df1); setDT(df2); df1[, v := df2[.SD, on=.(ID, DATE = PMT_DATE), roll=TRUE, x.STATUS]]`

Comment: Or a non-equi join: `df1[df2, on = .(ID, PMT_DATE > DATE), STATUS := i.STATUS][]`